# How to view website with only media that applies to print?

Tags: css, printing, media-queries, chromium, print-css

I am trying to setup a page on our site to work properly with printing, the issues I am hitting is that, to test it I need to keep printing to file.

What I would prefer would be if there was a way to display the page as it will be printed.

Is this possible? (Chromium).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify different CSS for different needs. Look at this style of coding CSS...

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media screen
  {
  p.test {font-family:verdana,sans-serif;font-size:14px;}
  }
@media print
  {
  p.test {font-family:times,serif;font-size:10px;}
  }
@media screen,print
  {
  p.test {font-weight:bold;}
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
....
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not what I am after, I know you can specify different media, but I want to be able to view the site as it will look (approximately) when it is printed, I don't want to have to keep using "Print to pdf" to see what it will look like, I am looking for a "Use print stylesheets" option or similar.

Comment: Going to print... in the settings of chrome would generate a preview of how the site looks in print... Isn't that what you wish to have ?